# Migrate from Hadoop to BigQuery - data cost estimates

Tags: hadoop, hive, google-bigquery, hortonworks-data-platform

We are considering to migrate from Hadoop/Hive to BigQuery. Since BigQuery charges per amount of data queried we are trying to make some cost estimates.

Is there any way to measure how much data is processed daily by all processes in the Hadoop cluster? Not sure if it will help but we are running everything through Hive, no direct MapReduce.

I understand this will be only an approximation since BigQuery charges per processed columns. It should give us a good upper estimate.

Eidt: We use Hortonworks.

Comment: Are you using CDH?  They have auditing (Navigator) which would allow you to aggregate the info.

Comment: @tk421 That's interesting, thanks. We are using Hortonworks though.